# Mounting an LVM EXT3 dd in linux

Tags: lvm, ext3

I'm using Ubuntu and am getting an error that tells me the filesystem can not be identified when I try to mount a LVM ext3 disk.  I'm passing "ext3" as the type and have been able to mount ext2 disks.  How can I mount the image?

Comment: What is the full command line you are passing to do the mount?  Have you attempted to leave "-t" off, or even try mounting it as ext2?

Comment: sudo mount -o loop,offset=106928640 <image_path.dd> /mnt      I get this error: "mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'"

Comment: Is the file an image of an entire disk?  Or of a single partition?  If the image is of a disk, does the disk have partitions or is the entire device an LVM PV?

Comment: Entire disk.  The first partition (boot) is recognized and mounted as /dev/sdb1 and the second partition is the LVM (sdb2)

Comment: Try 'losetup /dev/loop0 <img.dd>; kpartx -av /dev/loop0; vgdisplay; pvdisplay'? You'll need to have the partition recognised as a physical volume in your LVM volume group before you can mount the logical volume.

Answer (score 2):

LVM adds extra layers between the device and the filesystem; namely

- devices become Physical Volumes (PVs)
- PVs are part of a Volume Group (VG)
- VGs contain Logical Volumes (LVs)
- LVs contain filesystems

To access the filesystem on the image of an LVM disk, you need to

1. Loop-mount the image with `losetup /dev/loop0 <img.dd>`
2. Set up device maps with `kpartx -av /dev/loop0`
3. Check for volume groups, physical volumes and logical volumes with `vgdisplay`, `pvdisplay` and `lvdisplay`
4. Mount the relevant logical volume

Comment: This might not work if the image is an old image of the PVs in the system - then the UUIDs, VG names and LV names inside it could collide...